# Velocity Engine Ignoring @ character?

Tags: java, velocity

I'm using velocity v1.7 for sending email with JDK v1.7

I've below code:

```
VelocityContext context = new VelocityContext();
String name = "myname@yahoo.com";
context.put("userName", name);
```

And in the email template (abc.vm), I've used below code:

```
#if(${userName})        
    Dear ${userName},<br><br>
#end
```

Somehow, when I receive the email, it only says

```
Dear
```

instead of

```
Dear myname@yahoo.com
```

If I change the java code to have proper name without @ character, then email shows up properly

```
Dear myName
```

Can any one tell me why @ character is being skipped, in fact, why is it skipping entire name & not including it in the email????

Thanks!

Comment: Try `myname\\@yahoo.com`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to reproduce and the problems seems to be somewhere in the email sending. Velocity itself just renders this fine.

You can narrow down such a problem by writing the result from Velocity to the output, log or a file so you see what the text is at this point. Also debugging will show you what velocity returns and where in the email-sending there is a problem with special characters.

Code:
        VelocityContext context = new VelocityContext();

```
    context.put("name", "Velocity@mycompany.com");

    String name = "myname@yahoo.com";
    context.put("userName", name);

    Template template = null;

    template = Velocity.getTemplate("test.vm");

    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();

    try {
        template.merge(context, sw);
    } finally {
        sw.close();
    }
    System.out.println(sw);
```

Template:

```
Hello $name!

#if(${userName})        
    Dear ${userName},<br><br>
#end
```

Resulting Output:

```
Hello Velocity@mycompany.com!

    Dear myname@yahoo.com,<br><br>
```